# Problema al ejecutar script despues de sufrir un Java OutOfMemoryError con -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, shell-script, out-of-memory-error

Estoy intentando ejecutar un script cuando sufro un JavaOutOfMemoryError en una de mis aplicaciones.
El script se ejecuta dentro de las opciones de java

```
java.extended.properties=.......  -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=./script.sh.
```

Lo que sucede es que hay parte del script que si se ejecuta y otra que no.
Cuando o ejecuto el script funciona perfectamente, pero si fuerzo la aplicación a que sufra un desbordamiento de memoria , el script se queda ejecutándose y no hace nada, solo enviar el correo con parte del

el script.sh hace lo siguiente:

```
#!/bin/sh
JAVA=/jre64/11/bin/
PID=`cat .pid`
email="sistemas.servicios.cloud@it.es"
LOGFILE=alerta.log
> $LOGFILE
heap=`/jre64/11/bin/jcmd ${PID} VM.flags -all|grep MaxHeapSize | awk '{print $2$3$4}'|cut -f2 -d"="`
/jre64/11/bin/jcmd ${PID} GC.run
sed -i 's/-Xmx256/-Xmx512/' bwagent.file
echo "ATENCION!!.El agente acaba de sufrir un java OEM.Se ejecutaun GC del $PID" >> $LOGFILE
cat $LOGFILE|mail -s "AVISO IMPORTANTE! Notificacion de Alerta por OEM" $email
sleep 3
echo "$PID" >> ./debug.log
kill -9 $PID
nohup ./bwagent.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &
exit
```

cuando salta el script veo 2 ejecuciones

```
  2513 125 ./bin/sh -c script.sh
  1524 2513 ./bin/sh -c script.sh
```

¿Alguna idea de qué puede estar sucediendo?

Gracias